# How to specify custom css class for kendo.Window()?

Tags: jquery, css, telerik, kendo-window

I built kendoWindow and need to create my custom class for its title, so I do not use common classes provided by telerik.

This is my window:

```
$("#win").kendoWindow({
    visible: false,
    modal: true,
    title: true,
    open: function (e) { $("html, body").css("overflow", "hidden"); },
    close: function (e) { $("html, body").css("overflow", ""); },
    draggable: false,
    width: 950,
    height: 510,
    position: {
        top: 100,
        left: 500
    },
    resizable: false
});
```

It generates the following html:

[image]

I'm looking for the way to modify the way the title is generating by using my own class, instead of using existing one `k-window-titlebar k-header`

How can I do something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is how you can customize any CSS class in Kendo UI:

```
//You need to first make sure the window is initialized - if you are not using Kendo wrappers 

$("#myWindow").kendoWindow({
  // put your settings here
});

// Now you can add a custom CSS class after window initialization

var winObject = $("#myWindow").data("kendoWindow");
winObject.wrapper.addClass("myCustomClass");

// Here you can add a custom CSS class in the open event handler

function onWindowOpen(e) {
    e.sender.wrapper.addClass("myCustomClass");
}
```

Let me know your results!

Comment: I did the following and it worked for me: ` $('#win_wnd_title').closest("div").addClass("customTitle")`

Comment: That works too! My above example is for defining more complex (and multiple) custom classes, so keep that in your back pocket.